# How to get next dates after selecting a single date with a gap of 7 days

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let inputDate = document.querySelector(".inputDate"),
  submit = document.querySelector(".submit"),
  currentDate = document.querySelector(".currentDate"),
  dateAfter = document.querySelector(".dateAfter"),
  futureDays = document.querySelector(".futureDays");

submit.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  futureDays.innerText = "";

  let newDate = new Date(inputDate.value);

  let something = newDate / 1000;
  let something2 = new Date(something * 1000);
  let firstDate =
    something2.getDate() +
    "-" +
    (something2.getMonth() +
    1 )+
    "-" +
    something2.getFullYear();
  

  let inSeconds = Math.floor(newDate.getTime() / 1000);

  let myArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let sixDays = Math.floor((newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7) / 1000));
    
    let newDateFormat = new Date(sixDays * 1000);
    myArr.push(
      "  " +
        newDateFormat.getDate() +
        "-" +
        (newDateFormat.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        newDateFormat.getFullYear() +
        "  "
    );
    // myArr.push(sixDays);
    futureDays.innerText = myArr;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="date" name="" id="" class="inputDate" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY">
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="currentDate"></div>
<div class="dateAfter"></div>
<div class="futureDays"></div>
```

I am trying to get the next 5 dates after a particular date ( user provided ) with a gap of 7 days in between. I was able to get the next 5 dates and store them in an array, however I am unable to get the first date that was user selected in the array.

JS:

```
submit.onclick = (e) => {

  e.preventDefault;
  futureDays.innerText = "";

  let newDate = new Date( inputDate.value );
  
// First Date
  let something = newDate / 1000;
  let something2 = new Date(something * 1000);
  let firstDate =
    something2.getDate() +
    "-" +
    (something2.getMonth() +
    1 )+
    "-" +
    something2.getFullYear();
  

  let myArr = [];

  for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

    let sixDays = Math.floor( ( newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7 ) / 1000 ) );
    
    let newDateFormat = new Date( sixDays * 1000 );
    myArr.push(
      "  " +
        newDateFormat.getDate() +
        "-" +
        (newDateFormat.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        newDateFormat.getFullYear() +
        "  "
    );

    futureDays.innerText = firstDate + myArr;
  }
};
```

The first date comment, in this I am able to get the first date ( user provided ) and was able to add it in the array, but **is there a way that by default the user selected date is included in the array.**

Comment: The question is unclear. Please transform your code into a snippet where the problem reproduces, provide sample data and describe how the result is wrong.

Comment: I updated the question with the snippet, basically the program tells the next 5 dates with a gap of 7 days in between but it should include the first date i.e. the date selected by the user. I am unable to get the user selected date in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify it as the array element when you initialize the array, like:

```
let myArr = [inputDate.value];
```

```js
let inputDate = document.querySelector(".inputDate"),
  submit = document.querySelector(".submit"),
  currentDate = document.querySelector(".currentDate"),
  dateAfter = document.querySelector(".dateAfter"),
  futureDays = document.querySelector(".futureDays");

submit.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  futureDays.innerText = "";

  let newDate = new Date(inputDate.value);

  let something = newDate / 1000;
  let something2 = new Date(something * 1000);
  let firstDate =
    something2.getDate() +
    "-" +
    (something2.getMonth() +
    1 )+
    "-" +
    something2.getFullYear();
  

  let inSeconds = Math.floor(newDate.getTime() / 1000);

  let myArr = [inputDate.value];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let sixDays = Math.floor((newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7) / 1000));
    
    let newDateFormat = new Date(sixDays * 1000);
    myArr.push(
      "  " +
        newDateFormat.getDate() +
        "-" +
        (newDateFormat.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        newDateFormat.getFullYear() +
        "  "
    );
    // myArr.push(sixDays);
    futureDays.innerText = myArr;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="date" name="" id="" class="inputDate" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY">
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="currentDate"></div>
<div class="dateAfter"></div>
<div class="futureDays"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it works, what if I don't want to store the new dates in an array as in just print them out as is with the user selected date too?

Comment: @alittlehotcurry then instead of calling `push`, you could do something like `futureDays.innerText += "  " +
        newDateFormat.getDate() +
        "-" +
        (newDateFormat.getMonth() + 1) +
        "-" +
        newDateFormat.getFullYear() +
        "  "`

Comment: I tried that in that case it won't show the user selected date by default unless I refer and calculate the user selected date.

Comment: @alittlehotcurry of course initially you set `futureDays.innerText = myArr[0];`, just before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

// using date-fns for ease

```
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

const startDate = new Date(); // or user provided date
let daysNeeded = [];
const gap = 5;

daysNeeded.push(startDate);
for(let i = 1;  i<=5 ; i++) {
  daysNeeded.push(dateFns.addDays(startDate , i + gap))
}

console.log('days', daysNeeded);
```